# Why is System.arraycopy not camelCased?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Java's standard libraries seem to use camelCase for method names. *Native* functions like `nanoTime()` are no exceptions.

If so, why is  `System.arraycopy` not camelCased?

Is there something special about `System.arraycopy`?

Comment: I suspect there is no reason other than someone failed to enforce standards and inconsistency crept in.  But it would be interesting if it signified something else.

Comment: I have the same question about `Hashtable`. There is HashMap, ArrayList, LinkedList, LinkedHashMap, HashSet, TreeMap, TreeSet, PriorityQueue.....why not HashTable?

Comment: it's something that can be hashted.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's been in Java for before v1.0 was released - so my guess is that it predates the naming conventions, and it was missed in a sweep of the API when the naming conventions *were* decided.

(In other news, `NullPointerException` should be called `NullReferenceException`.)

Comment: I dont think so. There is `System.getenv()` which was added in JDK 1.5

Comment: @Nerdtron: Assuming you mean a direct address in memory, it doesn't have to be. Have a look at http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops for example.

Comment: @Kowser, getenv is as ancient as arraycopy

Comment: @Kowser: An *overload* was added in JDK 1.5, but `System.getenv(String)` was present in 1.0.2: http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/javadoc/java.lang.System.html#_top_

Comment: Nice info =D Btw is this also the same case for the "Hashtable" as Bhushan has pointed out above?

Comment: @JonSkeet that is interesting

Comment: @Pacerier: That's a little more forgivable; sometimes they're called "hash-tables" or even just "hashtables" in normal language. Not *very* much, admittedly. But note how Microsoft followed suit on that one :)