# Naming Convention Used by Java - Why the Inconsistency?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

This page is a good example of it. We have three different styles on this one page:

1. Fully named camel case (e.g. `clearProperty`)
2. Acronym-style (or C-style) abbreviation (e.g. `gc` for garbage collector)
3. No camel case or _ (e.g. `println` or `arraycopy`)
   '
   What gives?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421103/why-is-system-arraycopy-not-camelcased

Comment: `println` is pretty standard in all languages.

Comment: The inconsistencies wrt the Java style guide  are explained by 1) the age of the class (arraycopy) + difficulty of fixing and 2) consistency with previous library designs (println) and normal usage (gc).